# I can't get intelisense to work when using Typescript in vscode

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm quite used to using Typescript and have used it in most of my front-end projects, however i wanted to use Typescript in NodeJs.

I ran into an issue where i couldn't see any intelisense from any module using `require()` (Doesn't matter what dependency)

**Javascript intelisense:**
[image]

**Typescript intelisense:**
[image]

No problems or warnings, I've checked that vscode is configured to use the correct Typescript version "4.1.5".
[image]

And I'm sure Typescript works correctly since i have no problems in my other projects not using CommonJs.

I found a lot of "fixes" around the internet, but none of them solved my problem. I've also tried to reset my vscode with no extensions and default settings.

**Dependencies**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.27",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sequelize": "^6.5.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.1"
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

EDIT: I did try installing @types/sequelize in devDependencies but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the types for `sequelize`

```
npm i @types/sequelize
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i did try to install the types for sequelize and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the interface of node require

```
interface Require {
    (id: string): any;
    resolve: RequireResolve;
    cache: Dict<NodeModule>;
    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    extensions: RequireExtensions;
    main: Module | undefined;
}
```

As you can see, it returns a any type object. To get intellisense try something like

```
import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize'
Sequelize...
```

Comment: This isn't the reason.

Comment: I'm only using CommonJs, and like the other one said this isn't the issue. Other people have reported not having these issues with require() in Typescript.

Comment: @Henrik you mean somthing like this?

import sequelize = require('sequelize');
sequelize.Sequelize...

Comment: import sequelize = require('sequelize'); Will work, but i want to use destructuring so i don't have to sequelize.Sequlize or sequelize.DataTypes.

It works perfectly fine in JavaScript, Typescript is a superset of JavaScript it should be able to use intellisense.